# Is “It may be not” correct?

Tags: word-order, negation

Can I say something like “No, it may be not” or is that wrong? I affirmed something and then I said “No, actually it may be not” (trying to say it may actually not be like that) and somebody told me it should be “No, it may not be”, but the former still sounds better to me.

Comment: Needs more context, what was the sentence that came  *before*? It could also be a spelling issue *maybe* vs *may be* it depends. More background detail, please.

Comment: Lol I really wouldn't like to share that, but I just affirmed something and then said “No, actually it may be not” (like saying it may not be like that).

Comment: I thought, I could help you. But may be not.  Maybe someone else can.

Comment: Related, but unfortunately the question was closed, the comments underneath are quite hepful though: [May be not and may not be](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/128919/may-be-not-and-may-not-be)

Comment: Also related: [What is the difference between “maybe” and “may be”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12849/what-is-the-difference-between-maybe-and-may-be?rq=1)

Comment: I appreciate it but I think it's substantially different from my question, I already know “It may be not something” is wrong, but I'm not so sure about “It may be not” (without anything after); thanks again though.

Comment: It would depend on the affirmation.  Given the right affirmation, you could add as an afterthought, *Actually, maybe not*, which would be equivalent to "Actually, [it is] maybe not [as I said]."   Or, if you don't strand **not**: "Actually, it may be not *as I just said.*"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a quote from a famous paper by Geoffrey K. Pullum, *Syncategorematicity and English infinitival to*:

> [A]lthough *not* can follow a finite auxiliary that is stranded by VP ellipsis, it is impossible to have *not* after a stranded nonfinite auxiliary. (Pullum 1982: 201–202)

Pullum's observation describes the following kind of data:

1. Bob is attending but Ben is not.
2. *Bob is attending but Ben might be not. (ungrammatical)
3. Bob is attending but Ben might not be.
4. Bob is attending but Ben might not.

In (1) we can see that the non-finite verb phrase *attending* has been ellipted from the  clause in the second coordinate, *Ben is not [<s>attending</s>]*. The word *not* here follows the tensed auxiliary (and therefore finite verb form) *is*. This sentence is therefore grammatical because *not* is following a finite verb form.

However, in sentence (2), the phrase after *not* has been ellipted, but the verb before *not* is the *non*-finite plain form of the verb *BE*. This verb has no tense and is therefore non-finite. This sentence is therefore not grammatical.

In example (3) where *not* precedes the non-finite verb form *be* instead of following it, the sentence is fully grammatical.

In (4) we see the word *not* preceding the ellipsis. However it occurs directly after the finite auxiliary verb *might*. So sentence (4) is also grammatical.

**The Original Poster's example**

> 5. *It may be not [<s>like that</s>]. (ungrammatical)
> 6. It may not be [<s>like that</s>].

In (5) the word *not* directly precedes the ellipsis site. However, the word *not* itself is preceded by the non-finite verb form *be*. It is therefore ungrammatical. In (6), however, the word *not* occurs before the verb and not before the ellipsis site. (6) is therefore perfectly fine.

---

**Note for grammar junkies**

One might wonder why this particular piece of data is so important. Well, in grammars such as *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*  it is argued that infinitival *to* is a subordinator. However, there is also a very compelling argument that the word *to* is non-finite auxiliary verb (yes, a radical idea). One piece of evidence that this is the case is that *not* cannot precede an ellipsis site when it directly follows the word *to*. In other words, *to* patterns in this respect like the non-finite auxiliary forms of *be* above:

- *Bob wants to go there but Bill wants to not. (ungrammatical)
- Bob wants to go there but Bill wants not to.

For further arguments explaining why *to* is probably a non-finite auxiliary verb see this paper by Robert Levine, 2012, [*Auxiliaries: TO's company*](http://www.ling.ohio-state.edu/~levine.1/publications/Levine_auxiliary_to.pdf).